# Android: setting the dimensions of a Dialog (what does "fill_parent" mean?)

Tags: android, layout, dialog

The Android Developer guidance on [Creating a Custom Dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog) specifies a layout that starts:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/layout_root"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:padding="10dp"
          >
```

If I use this code I get a dialog that sits in the centre of the screen with about 40 pixels of the underlying view visible on each side.

What exactly does "fill_parent" mean (for the width and height)?

Answer (score 1):

In answer to Octavian Damiean, I have written an app following the code set out in [Creating A Custom Dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog). I have put the specified java code in the blank application's onCreate method (after super.onCreate(...) and setContentView(...). In order to make it run I have changed the Java code where it says "Context mContext = getApplicationContext();" to "Context mContext = this;" and at the end I have added the line "dialog.show();" to display the dialog.

The resulting screen looks like this:

[image: this]

Although both height and width are set to fill_parent the width is a bit smaller than the screen width and the height is very much smaller than the screen height.

I don't think padding works the way you suggest. Changing it from 10dip to 0dip makes no discernible difference (there is still a gap between the edge of the screen and the edge of the dialog.) Changing it to 100 dip results in this:

[image]

I think that padding affects the spacing of objects within the View rather than the spacing of the View within its parent.

Comment: You're totally right with me being mistaken about the padding. Sorry for that. What I meant would be the margin.

Answer (score 0):

It actually means what it says. It fills the entire space of its parent container. In this case minus `10dip` on each side (i.e. left, top, right, bottom) due to the padding attribute. If it would be set to `wrap_content` instead it would take up only as much space as it needs to display its content.

Here is more information about [fill_parent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#FILL_PARENT) and here about the [ViewGroup.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html).

Comment: But "fill_parent" is specified for height as well as width, so why does the dialog only fill a small part of the vertical height of the screen?

Comment: @user250845: Without seeing a screenshot of what the problem is I can't tell for sure but my guess is that your LinearLayouts parents height is set to a certain dimension.

Comment: I can't see how to include screenshots here, so I have submitted my response to this as a new Answer.

Comment: I know is late but this might be of some help for future revisions. The layout params specified by the LinearLayout correspond to the view contained within the Dialog window. That means that they apply to the window, so if you put FILL_PARENT it will fill the parent window, being the size of the window of the size that actually is being displayed on your device. Hope this helps you or others.